# WKWebView in SwiftUI plays only sound for Vimeo video URLs on iPhones, while it works properly on iPads

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, wkwebview

I am facing issue with implementing WKWebView in SwiftUI for Vimeo Video Urls. The video plays great on IPads but plays only sound on Iphones.

[screenshot of the code running in Iphone vs Ipad Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbPLo.png)

**CODE:**

```
struct VimeoPlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let videoUrl = "https://vimeo.com/826437886"
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
        prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        prefs.preferredContentMode = .desktop
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
        config.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let url = URL(string: videoUrl) else {
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}
```

**I have tried the following:**

1. Searching for a solution to the problem and couldn't find one.
2. Changing the useragent and webview viewmode to Desktop mode
3. Allowing inline playing of the video
4. adding `?playsinline=1` parameter to the video urls